# R subset data by date and hour; for loop or sapply()?

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, sapply

Hypothetical data frame representing a herd of sheep with rfid chips on their collars. There are data collectors with modems attached to poles throughout the field. Every unique time a unique sheep gets within range of one of these poles, it counts as an 'event', which is stored in the arduino device attached to the modem on the pole. Each arduino device has an address, and roughly every five minutes, it calls out over the modem to report its status and number of events.

```
> head(wow)
  address        checkin_time status_id number_events
1      11 2016-08-08 00:04:40         7            10
2      11 2016-08-08 00:09:53         7            13
3      11 2016-08-08 00:15:06         7            12
4      11 2016-08-08 00:20:20         7            11
5      11 2016-08-08 00:25:33         7            13
6      11 2016-08-08 00:30:45         7             5
```

I am trying to create a new matrix which contains all of the unique dates as rows, and each unique hour within a day as the columns, and them sums the total number of events for that date-time.

Here is my my (truncated) code that does that:

```
allDays <- unique(as.Date(wow$checkin_time))
for (d in allDays) {
oneAM <- subset(wow, as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) >= as.POSIXct(paste(d,'00:00:00')) & as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) <= as.POSIXct(paste(d, '00:59:59')))
twoAM <- subset(wow, as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) >= as.POSIXct(paste(d,'01:00:00')) & as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) <= as.POSIXct(paste(d, '01:59:59')))
threeAM <- subset(wow, as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) >= as.POSIXct(paste(d,'02:00:00')) & as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) <= as.POSIXct(paste(d, '02:59:59')))
enter code here
. . .

elevenPM <- subset(wow, as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) >= as.POSIXct(paste(d,'22:00:00')) & as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) <= as.POSIXct(paste(d, '22:59:59')))
twelvePM <- subset(wow, as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) >= as.POSIXct(paste(d,'23:00:00')) & as.POSIXct(wow$checkin_time) <= as.POSIXct(paste(d, '23:59:59')))
dayAsHours <- c(sum(oneAM$number_events), sum(twoAM$number_events), sum(threeAM$number_events), sum(fourAM$number_events), sum(fiveAM$number_events), sum(sixAM$number_events), 
                sum(sevenAM$number_events), sum(eightAM$number_events), sum(nineAM$number_events), sum(tenAM$number_events), sum(elevenAM$number_events), 
                sum(twelveAM$number_events), sum(onePM$number_events), sum(twoPM$number_events), sum(threePM$number_events), sum(fourPM$number_events), 
                sum(fivePM$number_events), sum(sixPM$number_events), sum(sevenPM$number_events), sum(eightPM$number_events), sum(ninePM$number_events), 
                sum(tenPM$number_events), sum(elevenPM$number_events), sum(twelvePM$number_events))
dateMatrix <- rbind(dateMatrix, dayAsHours)
}
```

The above code worked for a single value of `d` when it was hard-coded in, but ceased to work when I surrounded it in a for-loop.

The error I get is:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Also, I know I should probably be using `sapply()` instead of a `for-loop` here, but I was having a hard time figuring out how to build the function. Would `wow` be the data asset the function would be applied to, or would it be `allDays`?

Any point in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Comment: `cut` will work on POSIXt data, so you could create two variables, one with just a date, and then another with the datetimes cut by hour and use **data.table** or **dplyr** to aggregate with those two and then reshape moving the cut by hour variable to the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to do what I believe you want is to use `format` to strip the date and hour from the `checkin_time`. Then using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
result <- wow %>% mutate(Date=format(checkin_time, format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                         Hour=format(checkin_time, format="%H")) %>%
                  group_by(Date,Hour) %>% 
                  summarise(number_events=sum(number_events)) %>%
                  spread(Hour, number_events)
```

Notes:

1. Use `mutate` to create columns `Date` and `Hour` from the stripped date and hour from `checkin_time`.
2. `group_by` `Date` and `Hour` and use `summarise` to `sum` up all the `number_events` for each `Date` and `Hour`.
3. Use `spread` from `tidyr` to create the tablular result with `Date` as rows and `Hours` as columns.

I modified your posted input data `wow` to add have more dates and hours:

```
wow <- structure(list(address = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), checkin_time = structure(c(1470629080, 
1470629393, 1470716106, 1470720020, 1470803133, 1470803445), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), status_id = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), 
    number_events = c(10L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 5L)), .Names = c("address", 
"checkin_time", "status_id", "number_events"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
##  address        checkin_time status_id number_events
##1      11 2016-08-08 00:04:40         7            10
##2      11 2016-08-08 00:09:53         7            13
##3      11 2016-08-09 00:15:06         7            12
##4      11 2016-08-09 01:20:20         7            11
##5      11 2016-08-10 00:25:33         7            13
##6      11 2016-08-10 00:30:45         7             5
```

Using this data:

```
print(result)
##Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
##Groups: Date [3]
##
##        Date    00    01
##*      <chr> <int> <int>
##1 2016-08-08    23    NA
##2 2016-08-09    12    11
##3 2016-08-10    18    NA
```

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant. I hadn't looked into dlplyr before, but I think I need to learn that library post-haste.